# CodeRush - Export type to file missing?

Tags: visual-studio-addins, coderush

I'm currently evaluating CodeRush and one thing that I liked most when reading the featurelist was the "Export type to new file" or similar functionality. Now that CodeRush runs within my IDE, I cannot find this functionality. Is there a plug-in required for it or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you possibly talking about the "Move Type to File" refactoring?  If so, it's pretty easy, I use it pretty much daily when I'm defining new classes.

Select a type's name (perhaps a class)
Hit your refactor key (Usually Ctrl-`) or click on the triple dot refactor icon
Select Move Type to File

I suggest watching some of Mark Miller's tutorial videos to really get you start with CodeRush and Refactor. The [training videos are located here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/Training.xml).